# definite integral of Gaussian function over polynomial of even powers

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I need to know if there is a unified solution in terms of $L$ and $a_i>0, i=0,...,L$ for following integral:
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sum_{i=0}^{L} a_ix^{2i}}dx$. If not, what if we specify $L$, e.g. $L=4$. Can we solve it for $L=4$? 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: As written, this integral diverges because of the behavior near $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question. The summation should be from 0 to L.

Comment: This might be a problem to be handled by the residue theorem, but the Gaussian factor makes it nasty.

Comment: This is what I thought myself. I personally believe that if $L$ is not specified, we can not obtain a unified solution that is true regardless of $L$. However, if we specify $L$, we can use residue theorem to obtain $\frac{1}{\sum_i a_ix^{2i}}$ as a summation of $\frac{b_i}{x+c_i}$ and/or $\frac{b_i}{x^2+c_i}$ .... and then try to solve it. But I am not sure about all these stuff and appreciate any useful hint.

Comment: as an update, I found that the roots of $\sum_{i=0}^{L} a_ix^{2i}$ (denoted as $r$) are all imaginary conjugates, and hence, we can write $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{L}a_ix^{2i}}=\sum_{i=1}^{L}\frac{b_i}{x^2+r_i}$. Then we can take the integral into the summation and use wolfram-alpha to obtain a closed form solution for each integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{b_ie^{-x^2}}{x^2+r_i}dx$. The only question remains is how to obtain the roots $r_i$, for example for $L=4$?

Comment: I am Sorry for my repeated comments. I think if we assume $y=x^2$, we can obtain the roots of $\sum_{i=0}^{L} a_i y^{i}$ (denoted as $t_i$) and then obtain $r_i=\sqrt{t_i}$, which can be solved only if $L<=4$.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary polynomial, chances of a closed-form expression are nil.

Because there will be no closed-form for the indefinite integral (think that even a pure Gaussian requires a special function), and a definite integral with parameters is tantamount to an indefinite one.

Indeed, as the denominator is an arbitrary polynomial, by a shift of the variable you get another polynomial, hence the lower bound being $0$ is immaterial.

Alpha gives up for a simple case such as with $L=1$,

$$\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}dx.$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-x%5E2)%2F(x%5E2%2B1)

---

I am not even referring to the fact that $L=4$ yields a quintic polynomial in $x^2$, for which it has since long been proven that no closed-from expression exists. (After extremely arduous computation, you can reduce one to the Bring-Jerrard form, $x^5-x+y=0$, requiring an ad-hoc transcendental function.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the first part of your answer, I should say that, by "closed-form solution" I meant something in terms of "erfc(x)" which is easily available in a look-up table. Moreover, because the denominator has a constant term at $i=0$, the lower bound of integration can actually be zero, and the integration does not converge. Also, if you look at the following link, you will see that a definite integral of this function for $L=1$ has a solution using Wolfram.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-x%5E2)%2F(x%5E2%2B1)+from+0+to+inf

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer, as I said before, if we consider $y=x^2$ and $L<=4$, it yields a polynomial of degree 4 in terms of $y$ that can be solved. For bigger values of $L$, there is no solution.